# How to remove moisture absorber (Damprid) spill on drive way?

Tags: cleaning, driveway, chemicals, stain-removal

I spilled Damprid (calcium chloride) on a concrete driveway and it's making a stain due to the chemical staying on concrete and absorbing moisture. I sprayed water on the affected area and wiped away and dried using paper towels. It initially seemed to have worked but after 12 hours, the stain came back as if nothing was done. It seems that calcium chloride is embedded in the concrete and it's difficult to get it out...

What method or chemical should I use to remove the stain?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Googles, DampRid is primarily made of calcium chloride.  Try various methods for removing CaCl stains, e.g. vinegar.